# How to use custom vertex and fragment shader to draw 2d rectangle?

Tags: python, gpu

I want to use custom vertex and fragment shaders to draw 2d rectangles.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator

import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


class ModalOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def overlay(self):
        shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
        shader_info.push_constant('MAT4', "ModelViewProjectionMatrix")
        shader_info.vertex_in(0, 'VEC2', "pos")
        shader_info.fragment_out(0, 'VEC4', "FragColor")

        shader_info.vertex_source(
            "void main()"
            "{"
            "  gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0f);"
            "}"
        )

        shader_info.fragment_source(
            "void main()"
            "{"
            "  FragColor = vec4(pos, 1.0);"
            "}"
        )

        shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
        del vert_out
        del shader_info

        vertices = [
            (100, 100), (300, 100),
            (100, 200), (300, 200)]

        indices = (
            (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)
        batch.draw(shader)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self._2d_handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.overlay, (), "WINDOW", "POST_PIXEL")
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {"WHEELUPMOUSE", "WHEELDOWNMOUSE"}:
            return {"PASS_THROUGH"}

        elif event.type in {"RIGHTMOUSE", "ESC"}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._2d_handle, "WINDOW")
            context.area.tag_redraw()
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}


classes = (ModalOperator,)


register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I am getting this error

> ERROR (gpu.shader): pyGPU_Shader VertShader:
> | Error: C1067: too little data in type constructor
>
> ERROR (gpu.shader): pyGPU_Shader FragShader:
> | Error: C1503: undefined variable "pos"
>
> shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
>
> Exception: Shader Compile Error, see console for more details

Comment: There's an example for _exactly_ this in the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#triangle-with-custom-shader). Position needs to be vec3, not vec2, and you need to pass the position from the vertex shader to the fragment shader with a GPUStageInterfaceInfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing GPUStageInterfaceInfo, and you should use VEC3 instead of VEC2.

It is surprising that python does not generate an error when trying to delete an attribute that does not exist (del vert_out), I learned something new :)

````py
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def overlay(self):
        vert_out = gpu.types.GPUStageInterfaceInfo("my_interface")
        vert_out.smooth('VEC3', "pos")
        
        shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
        shader_info.push_constant('MAT4', "ModelViewProjectionMatrix")
        shader_info.vertex_in(0, 'VEC3', "position")
        shader_info.vertex_out(vert_out)
        shader_info.fragment_out(0, 'VEC4', "FragColor")

        shader_info.vertex_source(
            """void main()
            {
              pos = position;
              gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
            }"""
        )

        shader_info.fragment_source(
            """void main()
            {
              FragColor = vec4(pos, 1.0);
            }"""
        )

        shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
        del vert_out
        del shader_info

        vertices = [
            (100, 100, 0), (100, 200, 0), (300, 200, 0), (300, 100, 0)
            ]

        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRI_FAN', {"position": vertices})
        batch.draw(shader)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self._2d_handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.overlay, (), "WINDOW", "POST_PIXEL")
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {"WHEELUPMOUSE", "WHEELDOWNMOUSE"}:
            return {"PASS_THROUGH"}

        elif event.type in {"RIGHTMOUSE", "ESC"}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._2d_handle, "WINDOW")
            context.area.tag_redraw()
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}


classes = (ModalOperator,)


register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Hello @Oxicid, thanks for the answer. I need your further help, can you make the corners for the rectangle rounded and if possible also add an outline with the fragment shader? I don't know `GLSL` shader language  